# Is the story of Kaka Bhusundi mentioned in any puranas?

Tags: puranas, identification-request, ramcharitmanas

One of the famous stories from the [Ramcharitmanas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramcharitmanas) is the story of [Kaka Bhusundi](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2954/who-was-kakabhusundi/2955#2955). This brahmin Bhusundi was a devotee of Rama was cursed by sage Lomasa to become a crow. After knowing that he was an ardent devotee of Sri Rama, the sage diluted the curse and gave him the knowledge. By this knowledge, this crow has lived through the kalpas and seen different outcomes of Ramayana and Mahabharata.

However this story doesn't appear in the Vālmiki Rāmāyaṇa. I know that this story is also present in Yoga-Vāsiṣṭha which is also known as Vaśiṣṭa Rāmāyaṇa. I'm looking for sources other than this text.

So, my question is from which purana or scripture did Goswami Tulsidas know the story of Kaka Bhusundi?

Comment: I heard about him that he was the first and last person whom Rama showed his Vishnu form. He came to play with Rama (when Rama was baby). But one day he got doubt that he actually Vishnu himself, then Rama showed him his true form. And Rama gave him boon that Kaal won't be able to defeat you. You will live as long as you want. And he gave boon of devotion to him.

Comment: yoga vasista mentions him. Is that scripture ok or you need only from puranas?

Comment: I learned it from [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2954/who-was-kakabhusundi/2955#comment59888_2955) comment by Dr.Vineet Aggarwal. I'm looking other scriptures than Yoga Vashishta. They may be Puranas, Vedas, Brahmanas, Upanishads etc.,

Comment: I have not come across this story anywhere except Yoga Vasista and Ramcharitamanas.  But my knowledge may not be complete.

Comment: You should edit your question to clarify that you're looking for scriptures other than the Yoga Vasistha.

Answer (score 2):

His name in the context of a long-living crow is found in the Garga-samhita chapter 2.13:

> “... O Aśvaśirā, hear My words. Don't lament. Please don't lament. You will have the form of a crow, but you will have transcendental knowledge. You will have yoga-siddhis and the highest knowledge in the three worlds.”
>
> Śrī Nārada said: “After speaking these words, Lord Viṣṇu departed. O king, then the sage Aśvaśirā became the crow Bhuṣuṇḍa on Mount Nīla.”
>
> “He was devoted to Lord Rāmacandra. He was very powerful. He was a lamp shining on the meanings of all the scriptures. To Garuḍa he recited the Rāmāyaṇa.”
>
> [source](http://devoteesvaishnava.blogspot.com/2010/01/sri-garga-samhita-canto-two-volume-two_6253.html)