# What is the story of Kakabhusundi

Tags: shiva, ramayana, rama, avatars, yuga

When I searched for Kakabhusundi on wikipedia, it was written that -----

> The conversations happen between Shiva and Parvati, Sages Bharadwaj
> and Yajnavalkya and finally Kakbhushundi and the king of birds,
> Garuda.It has also been said that whenever Lord Rama takes an
> incarnation on earth in different ages Kalpa (aeon), Kakbhushundi
> flies away and shift to Ayodhya to watch the child plays of Rama,
> because of his devotional love for Rama.

But in Devdutt Patnaik's Sita it is written -----

> Kakabhusundi had listened the Ramayana from Lord Shiva.

So, which of the above to believe?

Comment: Sorry but it doesn't

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2954/who-was-kakabhusundi This should answer your question certainly.

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2954/who-was-kakabhusundi This should answer your question certainly